# Extracting cookies from a Mojolicious user agent response

Tags: perl, user-agent, lwp-useragent, mojolicious

I started using the Mojolicious library for testing and everything was working fine in until I tried to extract cookies from a response.

I've tried several variants of:

```
$ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new();
$ua->on( error => sub { my ($ua, $error) = @_; say "This looks bad: $error"; } );
$ua->max_redirects(1)->connect_timeout(10)->request_timeout(20);
$ua->cookie_jar(Mojo::CookieJar->new);

# ... later ...

my $tx  = $ua->get($url);
my $jar = $ua->cookie_jar->extract($tx); # This is undef
```

I can however extract the cookies via LWP::UserAgent. However, LWP has several different issues that make that option unworkable for now. Just for a comparison here is the LWP code that does extract the cookies.

```
my $lwp = LWP::UserAgent->new(cookie_jar => {}, timeout => 20, max_redirect => 1);
push @{ $lwp->requests_redirectable }, 'POST';
my $response = $lwp->get($url);
die $response->status_line unless $response->is_success;
$lwp->cookie_jar->scan(\&ScanCookies);

sub ScanCookies {
   my ($version, $key, $value) = @_;
   say "$key = $value";
}
```

So I know that I have the $url etc. correct.

Edit: I should mention that i'm using strawberry 5.14

Edit2: I should also mention that the cookies are getting into the user agent for sure, because the session ID is getting handled properly. Unfortunately, I have a need to access another cookie (for testing the site) and I just don't seem to be able the get the right incantation to access them... saying that I believe this to be a programmer problem and nothing more.

Comment: I wonder what symbols the $url contains... could you check that $key is really equal to $url in your ScanCookies?

Comment: Well it has some query parameters in the URL. Nothing too weird tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$tx->res->cookies
```

Comment: Right the docs say I should be able to do to use that as an array ref. but say scalar( @{$tx->res->cookies}); yields a 0;

Comment: May be response don't have cookies? Try `MOJO_MAX_REDIRECTS=1 perl -MMojo::UserAgent -E '$u = Mojo::UserAgent->new; say($_->name, "\t", $_->value) for @{($u->get("http://google.com/"))->res->cookies}'`.

Comment: I did this with slight modifications (because of windows) and I got cookies. Hmm... I know I'm getting a redirect from my web server. I wonder if the 302 reply has cookies and not the following 200 reply. Let me curl and see. [later] Confirmed, the initial 302 has the cookie. Now the question is is this important? I thought that cookies should be building up in the jar... but I'm trying to extract them from the reply so... think it thru t4 :)